# How to define the scope of subscript in a iteration?

Tags: subscript

Newbee to MMA, and completely have no clue about it.
I need do a calculation of some iteration, seen in the picture below.

$n=3,4,5,...,
\begin{cases}
L_n=c_n\\
L_{n-1}=c_{n-1}\\
L_{n-p+1}=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{p-2} (p-r-1)\;c_{p-r-1}\;L_{n-r+1}+c_{n-p+1}\;(p=3,4,5,...,n)\\
\end{cases}$

And for convenience and necessity,n equals 8. And the code is editted as

```
Subscript[L, 8] = Subscript[c, 8]
Subscript[L, 7] = Subscript[c, 7]
Subscript[L, 9 - p] =  
 Sum[(p - r - 1)*Subscript[c, p - r - 1]*Subscript[L, 9 - r] + 
        Subscript[c, 9 - p], {r, 1, p - 2}](*p=3,4,5,6,7,8*)
```

2 problems are encountered here.

**Problem 1:**

$c_1$ to $c_8$ is considered as constants with no certain values. Which code is needed to make it happen?

**Problem 2:**

As can be seen in the last part of my code, p has a range from $3$ to $8$. And again, which code is needed?

After searching so much info on the Internet, no solution is acquired....

Comment: Being a newbee, **avoid** `Subscript`. It is made for formatting, not calculations. For your indexed symbols, simply use `c[8]`, `L[7]` etc. You can use a `Do` loop over `p` to get all the definitions done.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer  thank you for your advice about Subscript, but I do need use it for further programming, for the iteration presented here is just a small step in my work. And I will try Do loop. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in part with Marius Ladegård Meyer concerning `Subscript` : never use it in the left-hand side of a definition because you cannot easily remove it after. But I like using it on the right hand side. So,

```
L[8] := Subscript[c, 8]    
L[7] := Subscript[c, 7]    
L[k_] := Sum[((9 - k) - r - 1)*Subscript[c, (9 - k) - r - 1]*
    L[9 - r] + Subscript[c, k], {r, 1, (9 - k) - 2}]
```

remark the use of `:=` instead of `=` : delayed assignment
Also remark the substitution 9-p -> k  in defining the left hand side of the sum : read up on 'pattern recognition' to learn why you need a single argument there (like ' k ' and not a subtraction like ' 9-p ' )
and last but not least,`L[k_]:=`  read up on 'Patterns' and argument naming.
You'll get the hang of it soon enough. ;-)

Comment: Many thankssssss for your help. And the problem 1 is still no solved, that can Subscript[c, i](i=1,2,3,...,8) be considered as constants and how to do it? And after that, whether is it possible to get mathematical expressions of L[k_] you mentioned above? @Wouter

Comment: @Robin_Lyn : have you tried to use the definitions in my answer to express the values of L[k]  using  `Table[L[k], {k, 8}]`?  it produces `{6 Subscript[c, 1] + 5 Subscript[c, 5] Subscript[c, 7] + 
  6 Subscript[c, 6] Subscript[c, 8] + 
  4 Subscript[c, 
   4] (Subscript[c, 6] + Subscript[c, 1] Subscript[c, 8]) +....`

Comment: yes, I tried and it works~~~And the calculations followed are solved all the way down, for they are similar iterations. A huge stone in my heart is taken away. Greaaaat jooooooy!